# In Swift on iOS/OSX how do I tell what error is thrown by a system function

Tags: ios, swift, macos, try-catch

For any given function that throws and error how do find out the error thrown?

For example, `class MTKTextureLoader` has a function that throws:

```
open func newTexture(with cgImage: CGImage, options: [String : NSObject]? = nil) throws -> MTLTexture
```

Fine. Throws what error exactly? My motivation here is I want to wrap this function in another function that can throw other errors.

Comment: You have to rely on the documentation. Objective C frameworks, such as MetalKit, will throw NSError: https://developer.apple.com/reference/metalkit/mtktextureloader/1661970-texture_error_handling. Swift framework/classes could throw ErrorType

Comment: Ah, right. Thx.